# Product of a family of spaces of countable tightness

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, cardinals

I recently learned the concept of cardinal functions and some of the definitions and theorems are not clear to me. How can we prove this theorem?

**Finite family of compact spaces of countable tightness 
has countable tightness.**

Evey compact space has countable tightness?

Comment: Have you looked in Engelking, chapter 3, in the exercises? Or in Cardinal Functions in Topology?

Comment: Another reference: V. I. Malyhin: On the tightness and Souslin number in exp X and in product spaces. Doklady AN SSSR 203 (1972),
1001-1003. Here he shows that if we have two countable tight spaces , ones of which is compact, then the product is countably tight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A corollary of Exercise 3.12.8 (d) of Engelking's “General topology” claims: if $f:X\to Y$ is a closed continuous map of topological spaces, $Y$ is regular, and for each $x\in X$ we have $t(f(x),Y)\le\kappa$ and $t(x,f^{-1}(X))\le\kappa,$ then $t(x,X)\le\kappa$.

Not every compact space has a countable tightness, because $t(X)=w(X)$ for each dyadic compact $X$, by Exercise 3.12.12 (h) of the same book.

Comment: YOU haven't answered the question.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky: The conclusion of this theorem is a little complicated to me. Please give more hints.

Comment: More hints. Let $X_1, X_2$ be compact (Hausdorff) spaces of countable tightness, and $f:X_1\times X_2\to X_1$ be the projection. Since $ X_1\times X_2$ is compact, $f$ is closed. Moreover, for each $(x,y)\in X_1\times X_2$ we have $t(f(x,y), X_1)=t(x,X_1)\le\omega$ and $t((x,y), f^{-1}(f(x,y)))= t((x,y),\{x\}\times Y)=t(y,Y)\le\omega$.